# angular pass array in get request

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass a query like that to the server:

```
/rest/articles/getTexts?tagIds[]=1&tagIds[]=88
```

I can do it with `$.param` like this:

```
var tagIds = [1, 88]
var param = $.param({tagIds: tagIds});
```

I've tried the same with angular:

```
var tagIds = [1, 88]
$http.get(serverUrl + "articles/getTexts" + {params:{tagIds: tagIds }})
```

But it produced the string like this:

```
/rest/articles/getTexts?tagIds=1&tagIds=88
```

Note the square brackets missing which leads to ovveriding of `tagIds` parameter on server side instead of making an array of it like in the case with jquery's param. Am I using angular's params in the wrong way or it's not possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: But this '/rest/articles/getTexts?tagIds=1&tagIds=88' is standard way to pass array in query string

Comment: Have you tried `params :{ tagIds: JSON.stringify(tagIds) }` ?

Comment: @salniro, this puts as a string instead of an array of values for a param.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, I guess it depends on how server side interprets them in such form. PHP ovverrides.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217941/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string-in-httpclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but if you want the param name to be `tagIds[]`, then that's also what the key of the params object should be:

```
params:{'tagIds[]': tagIds }
```